# Error in loadNamespace(name) Cairo

Tags: python, r, jupyter, cairo

It's my first time using `R` in `jupyter`. I've installed everything like `jupyter`, `python`, `R` and `lRkernel`. I can use just typing or calculation in jupyter but whenever I want to use a graph library like `plot` or `ggplot2` it shows

> Error in loadNamespace(name): there is no package called 'Cairo'
>   Traceback: plot without title

Someone please guide me about how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the precise same issue and fixed it by installing Cairo package:

`` install.packages("Cairo")`
library(Cairo) ``

Thanks to my collegue Bartek for providing this solution